# nunit and log4net

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, log4net

I am unable to test my log4net library using nunit. I read the search results returned by Google but could not understand them.

This is the error that I am getting.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

In my nunit test project I have added the reference to correct log4net dll that rest of the projects are using and added the configuration files but no luck.

My Console application and test web application that use the log4net libaray are working correctly.

I seem to only have problem with log4net nunit test project.

How can I get started with simple nunit test involving log4net library.

Comment: Have you changed project output folders? is CopyLocal of reference set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be accepting an ILog in whatever you're trying to test.  Then you should mock it and pass it to whatever you're attempting to test.  The version of log4net shouldn't matter at all.  Your tests shouldn't even know log4net exists.

Using Rhinomocks, this would be:

```
MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
ILog mockLog = mocks.DynamicMock<ILog>();
```

Alternatively you could go with a stub:

```
ILog mockLog = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ILog>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that `Version` of log4net.dll is same for your tests project and for projects which are referenced by tests (btw latest version of log4net is 1.2.11.0). Also verify that `Copy Local` is set to true.

If you are involving log4net library, then this is probably integration test, not unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the run-time log4net.dll file you have included. It looks like it could not match the .NET run-time CLR of your project. Check the target NET version of your app (Project -> Properties), and make sure it matches the target version of log4net.dll. Note version 1.2.11 of log4net includes binaries up to version 4.0, and also note client-profile versions are distinct than full versions, requiring their own specific dll files.